# rendering html from cs file to cshtml

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm creating some html code from a cs file, which i want to be rendered one the actual site.
But what I get rendered is the "raw" html code, not the rendered. What am I doing wrong?

the .cshtml code:

```
<div>
    @class1.createhtml();
</div>
```

the .cs code:

```
public static string createhtml()
{
    return "<p>hi</p>";
}
```

Comment: Did you try @Html.Raw(mystring)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(class1.createhtml())
</div>
```

You should be very careful that you don't put unescaped user-input into this string, or you open up the door to injection attacks - treat this with the caution that you might treat appending strings to make a SQL query: avoid it if at all possible, or be very careful.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method in your view:

```
@Html.Raw(class1.createhtml())
```